# Variable in while loop

Tags: php

```
<?php

$countStart = some value from sql query for example 1;
$pageLimit = some value from sql query for example 5;

$i = $countStart;
while($i<=$pageLimit)
      {
      echo "The number is " . $i . "<br />";
      $i++;
      }
?>
```

If I put while($i<=5) it works. What am I doing wrong in above code? Thank you in advance.

Comment: what's the code for 'some number from sql query;'?

Comment: Hva you tried printing the value of `$pageLimit`? What did you see?

Comment: What is value of `$countStart`? is it always greater than `0`?

Comment: It looks like your SQL query returns a string, try to cast it to int. e.g: `while ($i <= intval($pageLimit))`.

Comment: try changing you while loop to `while(intval($i) <= intval($pageLimit))`

Comment: @nepalipunk check the var_dump status of output you r getting from the db query

Answer (score 0):

Check the contents of $pageLimit before the while loop. There shouldn't be any issues accessing the variable within the while statement.

Comment: If I do echo $pageLimit; then I get output 5. And if I put while($i<=5) it works, but it does not work if while($i<=$pageLimit)

Comment: You may need to convert the $pageLimit to an integer. A.k.a. use `$pageLimit = (int) your code`

Answer (score 0):

It look good but try display both values for example

```
echo $countStart;
echo $pageLimit;
die();
```

this can help you to catch error.

Comment: If I do echo $pageLimit; then I get output 5. And if I put while($i<=5) it works, but it does not work if while($i<=$pageLimit)

Comment: so I suggest you to show your code with real `some number from sql query` part. Maybe you have some syntax error there.

Answer (score 0):

You can put int before the
$pageLimit = (int)some number from sql query;